# Windows sets EFI boot settings on boot

Tags: windows-10, uefi

Every time I boot windows frim rEFInd, my bios EFI settings get changed to have the windows boot manager as the primary efi boot entry. This prevents me from booting into rEFInd until I go into the bios and change the primary boot entry back to rEFInd.

I assume this is being set by either (likely) windows or (less likely) my bios. I have an Asrock Extreme3 Gen3 mobo.

Anyone know how to tell windows not to do this?

I'm running an unregistered version of windows 10.

After booting to windows (through rEFInd):
[image: Boot order after booting to windows]

What I set to boot to rEFInd:
[image: Boot order I set to boot into rEFInd]

Boot options:
[image: List of boot options]

Comment: @Ramhound Care to explain? I doubt its getting set by rEFInd, and I don't think theres a way to have the bios automatically update the boot list (or to disable that)

Comment: @Ramhound I can boot to rEFInd over and over. As long as I boot into linux or shut off my computer (anything but boot into windows), I correctly get booted into rEFInd the next time. I'll try to post a picture or two of my bios settings.

Comment: Try using [EasyUEFI](http://www.easyuefi.com/index-us.html) in Windows to set rEFInd to the top of the boot list. If this fails, try using `bcdedit` in Windows, as in `bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\refind\refind_x64.efi` (typed in an Administrator Command Prompt window).

Comment: @RodSmith So EasyUEFI set the bios settings correctly; however it got set back to the windows boot manager after the next windows boot. Setting the windows boot manager to refind does ensure it is always refind that gets launched, even with the bios settings getting set to windows boot manager. So while this isn't perfect perfect, it does what I want. Thanks!

Comment: Shade, if you mean that rEFInd is now showing up in the EFI's boot manager as "Windows Boot Manager," you can rename it with `bcdedit /set {bootmgr} description "rEFInd Boot Manager"`. You might need to do this just after typing the first `bcdedit` command I recommended.